# User Input matrix(n*n+1) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

this code is out put a[i][j] start with a[0,0] but i want it start with a[1,1] How have i do??

```
import numpy as np
n = int(input("How many variable you find "))
a = np.zeros((n,n+1))
print('Enter Augmented Matrix:')
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n+1):
        a[i][j] = float(input( f'a[{i},{j}]= '))
print(a)
```

Comment: For me first ask is `a[1,1]= ` well, cna you copy your console output ? Your ranges starts at 1 so you canno't start at 0,0

Answer (score 0):

Using `range(n)` starts at `0` included, and `n` exlcuded, in math this is `[0;n[`, to start at `1` do `range(1, n)` giving you

```
for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
```

If you input `4` at first question, then fill with ones you'll get :

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

---

If you use the following it goes to far, because arrays are indexed `0-base`, so if you say an array is length 5, the box indexes are `0,1,2,3,4`

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, n + 2):
```

---

## SOLUTION

If you want to fill **all** values, but just change the thing you print for the user, do

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n + 1):
        a[i][j] = float(input(f'a[{i + 1},{j + 1}]= ')) # +1 there
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
   for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n+1):
            a[i][j] = float(input( f'a[{i},{j}]= '))
```

to this:

```
for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        a[i][j] = float(input( f'a[{i},{j}]= '))
```

Similarly you can try

```
 for i in range(n-1):
     for j in range(n):
         a[i+1][j+1] = float(input( f'a[{i},{j}]= '))
```

May I ask why do you want to start with a[1][1]?

Comment: I want to make matrix n*n+1 and user input every point and told them this point is row1 column 1

Comment: oh then your code should work as it is. The only difference is that since lists are zero-indexed they'll start with 0 and end with (n-1)th index, but you'll get the same matrix size regardless.